# Upload file from Azure storage directly into python variable

Tags: python, file-sharing, azure

I'm working on a Python code where we upload into local variables, big documents.
I want to put these documents into an Azure storage.

My problem is that I can't find a way to upload the files from the Azure storage to my python variable without downloading it(the file/document) locally into my laptop.

Is it technically possible to do so?

Comment: Question is a little confusing. Sounds like you want to retrieve a file from an Azure blob so you can access its contents as a variable in a Python program. Have you done any Azure programming from Python? Are you already using a particular Python module?

Comment: Hey chasbas,
I'm using azure.storage.file package to download the files locally on my laptop and then put it in a python variable. Buti'm looking for a way not to have the files locally (no downloads). I want to read them directly in the storage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm new at this too, but I think the following should work:

```
 from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
 bs = BlockBlobService(account_name='asdf', sas_token='fdas')
 gen = bs.list_blobs('containername')
 for blob in gen:
    print(blob.name)
 filedata = bs.get_blob_to_text('containername', 'blobname')
 print(filedata.contents)
```

[edit] Note that this only works for text files. Binary files will likely fail if you try this.